# "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" Neo4jClient Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am trying to put a where clause in my Neo4j cypher query to return some nodes, this is the query im trying to perform:

```
start n = node:node_auto_index(Name = "Contact Details") Match (n)--(x) Where x.Type = "Version" Return x;
```

Now my C# method looks like this(using Neo4jClient):

```
public IEnumerable<Node<VersionNode>> GraphGetAllVersionNodes(string nodeName)
        {
            clientConnection = graphOperations.GraphGetConnection();

            IEnumerable<Node<VersionNode>> queryResult = null;

                var query = clientConnection
                    .Cypher
                    .Start(new
                    {
                        n = Node.ByIndexLookup("node_auto_index", "Name", nodeName)
                    })
                    .Match("(n)--(x)")
                    .Where((VersionNode x) => x.Type = "Version")
                    .Return<Node<VersionNode>>("(x)")
                    .Results;
                queryResult = query.ToList();

            return queryResult;
        }
```

Now there is an error on the where clause saying:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's a verbatim copy-paste, then I'm guessing the issue is that you wrote:

```
.Where((VersionNode x) => x.Type = "Version")
```

When you need to write:

```
.Where((VersionNode x) => x.Type == "Version")
```

PS. What's the point of `IEnumerable<Node<VersionNode>> queryResult = null;` instead of just `var queryResult =`? You never assign it in any other path, so it's just a waste of code and an extra signature to maintain.